# Please help, was it a stake or a cross?

Tags: greek, crucifixion

Good morning all,

Forgive my ineptitude. As I was told for many years of my life that Jesus was crucified upon a cross, I imagined it as many do as a "t" shaped cross. I have now been informed of a term "stauros" or "xylon" that refers to it as a stake.

Please, anyone with insight on this clarification or helping me understand is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!